# this.$router.push is not pushing props as expected

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3

I am trying to navigate from one page to another and pass props to the new page component. This is my `router.push`:

```
this.$router.push({
  name: 'settings',
  params: {
    theme: 'dark'
  },
  props: true
})
```

And the other component looks like this:

```
export default {
  name: 'settings',
  props: ['theme'],
  mounted() {
    console.log("on mount: " + this.$props.theme)
    console.log(this.$route.params.theme)
  }
}
```

Why is `theme` always `undefined`? How can I get its value? It is correctly navigating to the page but I am unable to access any props.

Comment: I tried replicating this on my end, and I did not get this issue. I wonder what is going on

Comment: What does your route path look like?

Comment: Same as what was added in the initial question code block

Comment: Looks like with one of the newest Vue updates, you can no longer pass props as params if the route does not specify that it can take params. I find it dumb because now I would have to make the values visible in the URL which does not fit my use case. Heres the link: https://github.com/vuejs/router/blob/main/packages/router/CHANGELOG.md#414-2022-08-22

Comment: Well, it is an anti-pattern, as they say in release notes you linked to, and there are plenty of alternatives. As you seem to be using it for a theme name, could you rather not store it in some sort of more global state? Such as a composable or even Pinia.

Comment: If you had updated Vue Router to the next version (released four days after the one that introduced the change), you would have received a warning that the param would be discarded. Did you look in your DevTools?

Comment: I admit, though, this is quite a change to introduce in a patch version, even if it is technically not a feature and should never have been used.

Comment: Yeah I ended up using Reactive.js https://vuejs.org/api/reactivity-core.html

Comment: If you've solved your problem, please post an answer yourself (it's fine to answer your own question if you find a solution). This allows others to benefit as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was the easiest solution, using `reactive` store

```
// store.js
import { reactive } from 'vue'

export const store = reactive({
  theme: 'light',
})
```

And then wherever you want to use it:

```
import { store } from './store/store'

store.theme = 'dark'
```